# JavaScript `match` behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

In my Chrome console, I tried this out:

```
>  "abcd".match(/(.+)+/)
<  ["abcd", "abcd"]
```

the fact that `match` returned **two** 'results' was, to me, unexpected and odd. I tested in Firefox and the result was the same (so I presume it's not a bug of any sort).

However, in Python:

```
>  re.findall(r'(.+)+', 'abba')
<  ['abba']
```

I can't explain this. What's going on?

Comment: It has something to do with the capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as regexp.exec(string).

And from [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then
>   one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the
>   text that was captured.

So the first item in the returned array is the match (`"abcd"`) and the second item is the one and only parenthesized group (happens to also be `"abcd"`).

Comment: Oh! I see. Makes sense :) I added the `g` flag and it was down to one result.

Comment: @Abody97 "If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches." (nothing returned from grouping)

Answer (score 2):

I think in javascript, .match gives group 0 (entire matched expression w/o capture) as well as group 1 (captured group) whereas python's findAll behaves differently-- showing you only captured groups, and not the whole matched portion (group 0)

Comment: has nothing to do with chrome. this is how String.match works.

Comment: Sorry Kasapo! I was mistaken with my earlier comment.

Comment: np ithcy, and @jbabey, you are of course right and my misleading statement has been corrected -- I now reference javascript as behaving in this way and not the browser.